# How do I init socket in C++ without libraries

Tags: c++, sockets

I need to init socket in C++ (GNU GCC) without libraries. When I Googled it, it suggested to use WinSock Library or something like this. How to do this? Thank you for answers.

Comment: What do you mean without libraries ?

Comment: I assume he means third party libraries.

Comment: what system are you using? you mention gcc and then a windows library.

Comment: You'll need a documentation of your OS and some assembler skills if you want to do it "without libraries".

Comment: I bet if you google for '<your platform> socket programming' you will get a good amount of hits.

Comment: closest I've done is using `#include <sys/socket.h>`, decent tutorial at http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot. The C++ language as defined by the standard has no socket specification. To work with them, you necessarily have to use some implementation-specific libraries, like WinSock.

I would recommend you use Boost's ASIO library, which does all the hard and dirty work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Sockets are allocated by the operating system so you'll need to interface with the OS in some way.  In my experience with C++ using the GCC (I'm assuming Linux of some kind here) you will need to use the sys/sockets library.  Some higher level abstractions of the sockets library exist but I've never found one I was too happy with.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard does not provide for this. A good crossx library for this is [C++ PTypes](http://www.melikyan.com/ptypes/).